# SQL server code (UPDATE)

Tags: sql-server

i have a problem of how to update data from table A to table B and  make in horizontal from vertical..example is

```
Table A                -----------        Table B

ID -----   Item        -----------      ID ------Item

11---      iPhone4     -----------      11 ------iPhone4,iPhone4s,iPhone5   
11---      iPhone4s   
11---      iPhone5
```

mean that from 3 Rows become 1 rows.
Please help,really noob in this case..
Thanks

Comment: proper align your code and table structure

Comment: Why would you want to do that? you should read up on [database normalization](http://www.dbnormalization.com/). Also, when 3 different products have the same id, it kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: Do you want `Item` to be one column or you want 3 `Item` columns?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this..

```
Select ID,        
Left(Item,Len(Item)-1) As Items 
From(
    Select distinct T2.ID,
    (Select 
    T1.Item + ',' AS [text()]             
    From TableA T1                          
    where T1.ID = T2.ID
    For XML PATH ('')) [item]       
    From dbo.TableA T2  
    ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..Use GROUP_CONCAT to merge in one row the rows you want to merge.

```
SELECT ID,GROUP_CONCAT(item)
  FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY ID;
```